# how to open contacts in ionic native

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, contacts, ionic-native

My requirement is to open native contact using ionic native. I googled but could not get proper answer

We used this [ionic Native contacts plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/)

getting all contacts :

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      var opts = {   
         filter : "M",                                
         multiple: true,        
         hasPhoneNumber:true,                             
         fields:  [ 'displayName', 'name' ]
       };
       contacts.find([ 'displayName', 'name' ],opts).then((contacts) => {
         console.log(contacts);
        this.contactlist=contacts;
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
   })
```

Comment: Well, you should add what have you tried.

Comment: @DiegoCardozo we are  able to get all contacts but  we need open phone-book  ,we are not get any method name like open Phonebook.  please guide to us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But remember that in Ionic if you want to use a Native API you must first wait for `platform.ready()` this event will notify that everything has been loaded and it is ready to use.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Contacts, Contact, ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts';

constructor(private contacts: Contacts, private plt: Platform) {   
   this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
      console.log('Platform ready from', readySource);
      // Platform now ready, execute any required native code
      this.initContacts();
    });
}

initContacts(): void {
   let contact: Contact = this.contacts.create();

   contact.name = new ContactName(null, 'Smith', 'John');
   contact.phoneNumbers = [new ContactField('mobile', '6471234567')];
   contact.save().then(
     () => console.log('Contact saved!', contact),
     (error: any) => console.error('Error saving contact.', error)
   );

   // If you want to open the native contacts screen and select the contacts from there use pickContact()

   this.contacts.pickContact()
                .then((response: Contact) => { 
                   console.log(response)
                });
}
```

Comment: How should I select multiple contacts after open native contacts screen?

Comment: Well, the plugin won't help you here, you can create a custom component with the data from `navigator.contacts.find(['*'], (contacts) => {})` and you will handle the selection.